# Open a Password-Protected Word File in Java?

Tags: java, ms-office, password-protection

How can I open a password-protected Microsoft word(.doc, .docx) file in Java, assuming that the password is known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with com4j.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open2000.aspx

Since there is a parameter called "PasswordDocument" in the "open"-method, I think it is possible to open a password protected file.

Hope this is what you were searching for ;)

Edit: I recorded this Macro in Word.

```
Documents.Open FileName:="test.doc", ConfirmConversions:= _
    False, ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:= _
    "hallo", PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:= _
    "hallo", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto
```

So the open method in com4j should look somethin like this (password is "Hallo"):

```
     _Document document = app.documents().open2000(doc, false, false, false, "hallo", "", false, "hallo", "", WdOpenFormat.wdOpenFormatAuto, false, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be the Apache POI project which supports Office 97-2003 and OOXML (2007-2010) formats. If you are mainly interested in extracting text from those files, you should also look at the Tika project that has some good code, such as [OfficeParser.java](http://search-lucene.com/c/Tika:/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/OfficeParser.java)

You will want to substitute in your known password(s) around line 220 in the parse() method:

```
if (!d.verifyPassword(Decryptor.DEFAULT_PASSWORD)) {
throw new TikaException("Unable to process: document is encrypted");
}
```

-- the default password is set to the mostly useless password "VelvetSweatshop" (!)

Comment: VelvetSweatshop is not just a curious string, in this instance - it is the default Excel password used when no password is set, but the workbook is "protected"...

Answer (score -1):

In our projects, we use [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) to manage Office documents, but we do not deal with password-protected documents, but I imagine that this library handles such cases...