# Need java code for opening password protected docx file

Tags: java, ms-word, docx

I want to unzip and read the password protected docx file in java. i want too know the algorithm used..please help me..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Will u be knowing the password for the file ? or hacking some one password?

Comment: possible duplicate of [open a password protected word file in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675773/open-a-password-protected-word-file-in-java)

Comment: Are you working on the WikiLeaks poison pill file?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing Microsoft format documents (including docx) in Java is typically done with [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). You'll likely need to know the password for your password protected file.

Comment: Thanks.But u didnt get any code from there..how to get it buddy

Comment: All Apache code is open source. All the source code is there.